How to force the 'captive.apple.com' window to appear?
Background
Sometimes wifi networks require you to login via a 'captive' webpage that pops up when you try to connect to the network. This is quite common at airports, hotels and cafes.
This usually goes smoothly, but just like all software/hardware, occasionally there's some problem that requires you to close the captive.apple.com window and start again. But, that 'captive.apple.com' window doesn't always reappear when you want it to.
Current workaround
My current strategy is to:

Go Settings -> Wifi -> Click on three dots next to wifi network -> Forget this network. Then reconnect to the network. That often (but not always) prompts the 'captive.apple.com window' to appear.

If that doesn't work after a few attempts I turn wifi off and back on again.


Question
Is there some way to force the 'captive.apple.com' window to re-open for a given wifi network?
Notes

happy to use some terminal code if that can do the job.
probably safe to assume the desired wifi network is the last one the device attempted to join (in case that's relevant for any reason).


I just copy pasted this in to chatgpt and it says just to put this in the browser http://captive.apple.com. Could it be that simple!? (I hope so! but would dream of relying on an llm).

Usually you have to open a browser and try to go somewhere.  Captive portals are a problem on every platform, not just Apple.  I usually try going to http://si.com, once you find a link that the redirect will force the prompt to pop back up, you stick with it.
